# Hook system PHP

Tags: php

I need some help with PHP.

In the functions.php file from my site I created two functions

```
$hooks = array();

function addHook( $hook, $func) {
    global $hooks;
    $hooks[$hook][] = $func;
}
```

and

```
function addToHead() {
    global $hooks;
    foreach($hooks as $hook => $functions){
        if ( $hook == 'head' ) {
            foreach($functions as $function){
                call_user_func( $function );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call the addToHead() function in the head.php file.

And I call the function The addHook() where I need.

Because the addHook() function is called after the addToHead() function the addToHead function is not working.

Comment: Did you mean after calling addhook()??

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the hooks global before the function call.

```
global $hooks;
$hooks = array();

function addHook($hook, $func) {
    global $hooks;
    $hooks[$hook][] = $func;
}

print_r($hooks);
```

Or you can extend your function to use `use` and pass by reference.

```
$hooks = array();

function addHook($hook, $func) use (&$hooks) {
    $hooks[$hook][] = $func;
}

print_r($hooks);
```